# Xamarin.Forms bug fix? CAN'T SEE "iOS Build" in project properties of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

[image: Screenshot]I CAN'T SEE the iOS project properties in any new Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin.Forms project I create or open.

In the solution when I right-click on Properties of MyProjectName.iOS, the area where "iOS Build" is normally located in the tabbed view is replaced with a BLANK, UNLABELED tab. I do however see "iOS Application" and the other tabbed items below it.

Now, I CAN click on this blank tab where "iOS Build" is supposed to be visible and labeled but then I receive this error message:
**"An error occurred trying to load the page. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"**

To fix it I have tried the following:

```
1. Restoring NuGet packages
2. Updated Xamarin, Visual Studio (Update 3)
3. Checking and re-coding the Info and Entitlements plist files
4. Deleting packages and rebuilding
5. Removing/Re-adding the project
6. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
7. Closing and reopening Visual Studio 2015
8. Repairing Visual Studio 2015 completely
9. In Visual Studio went to Help > Xamarin > Open Logs and tried to detect something there.
```

I believe the issue is with the software though because any solutions I download from GitHub or create in a new project also have the "iOS Build" page missing.

Does anyone know a fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: In Visual Studio go to Help > Xamarin > Open Logs and try to detect something there

Comment: Nothing in there that I can see.  I re-simulated the error repeatedly and nothing was ever added into the logs either.  Thanks

Comment: I had same issue. It will be fixed when connected to mac server and open it.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this and see if it works

Comment: Might be a while until I test as I am going on vacation for a week...let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kowalski said, once you are able to connect to the Mac Build Host successfully that error will disappear and everything will work just fine again.